# Create individual feature classes for every record in a single feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, cursor, feature-class

I have arc desktop 10.3.  I have a feature class (nycd) with 59 records in it.  I'm trying to create a simple map with an inset that shows where each community district is located in that borough. I'd like to create an individual feature class for every record (with every field included) and put them in a file geodatabase (Comm_Snap) and am looking for different ways to do this. I'm not very familiar with arcpy but want to start utilizing it. I was initially thinking a simple script with a Search Cursor and a data management tool would work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might find this https://geonet.esri.com/thread/69684 useful.  You could then use something like `AddField_management` and an `InsertCursor` to create your fields and insert the sole record.

Comment: Is this to create a map for each record in your feature class - i.e. 59 maps? Have you looked into using [Data Driven Pages](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/page-layouts/what-are-data-driven-pages-.htm) rather than exporting each record as an individual feature class? Or is there more to what you intend to do?

Comment: For earlier duplicates look under Split By Attribute.